My 3D model is only hiding with alt+H and not with the hide button in the "explorer" tab
I am a noobie in Blender and I am trying to make a simple animation.
I am using this 3D model however when I try to hide it with the eye button it wont hide. If I use Alt + H it hides but I don't know if Alt + H creates a keyframe as I need it to be hidden then apear during the animation.
Here is the file

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

The explosion you've downloaded is actually made of a series of objects, each being a step of the explosion, and each being scaled down to be invisible, then scaled up to be visible, then scale down to be invisible again. So it's not a classical object that you could hide and unhide, if you want to scale the explosion at a certain frame, remove all the objects that are supposed to follow (or hide them or scale them down).
Example: at frame 218 it is the empty cube.051_22 that is scaled up and it makes it child (the mesh object) visible:

At the next frame empty cube.051_22 will be scaled down so that it is invisible and it's another empty that is scaled up:

Former answer:
You can keyframe the icons in the Outliner, the eye icon only set the visibility for preview, if you want to make the object invisible for render you need to keyframe the camera icon. You can also keyframe the options in the Object panel > Visibility:


I have tried doing this however it did not work.

Maybe share your file, only keep the object that you want to hide

okay I will do that.

I just uploaded the file with just the object needed.

OK I've edited my answer

Thank you the scaling up an down worked perfectly!
